# ,5 rounds down/up every other calculation

Tags: vb.net, math, decimal, currency, rounding

```
Label4.Text = CDec(TextBox1.Text) * 115
Label5.Text = CInt(Label4.Text)
```

I want `Label4` to show the exact number and `Label5` to show that number without decimals and rounded up.

If I type 11,1 in the textbox, `Label4` = 1276,5 and `Label5` = 1276 (why rounded down?).

If I type 11,3, `Label4` = 1299,5 and `Label5` = 1300 (perfect).

11,5 is rounded down; 11,7 is rounded up...and on so on.

How can I make it so ,5 is always rounded up? (I am working on money-based calculations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using VB.NET you can use `Math.Round`:

```
Label5.Text = = Math.Round(CDec(Label4.Text), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Note that `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` is necessary since the default behavior for `Round` is to round `X.5` to the nearest *even* number (e.g. 1.5 rounds to 2.0, but 2.5 rounds *down* to 2.0).

---

<sup>As a side note, a minor optimization would be to store the result of the first expression in a decimal variable and reuse it rather than parsing `Label4.Text` again – but I didn't want that to detract from the actual answer.</sup>